# Trouble with displaying captured pic in Imageview (Android studio)

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio

I am using android Studio and I had my app working where I press a button to open my samsung galaxies camera and take a pic. I can then save the pic and it displays in an imageview within the application. However since today the picture does not display in the imageview. It still saves but dissappears after i take the picture. If I hold my phone sideway the image shows up at first but once i hold my device straight the image will vanish. I do not understand what this could be and I am new to android studios and to coding in general. If anyone could help that would be appreciated :) ? Also when the image dissappears, this error appears in the logs: 32351-32351/com.andyexample.myapplication E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null.

CODE FOR MAIN ACTIVITY:

public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity {

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
ImageView imageView;


//Drawable dirty;
//Bitmap bitmapImage;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);


    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Button openCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openCamera);
    Button buttonFilter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFilter);





}



//launching the camera

public void launchCamera(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    //Take the picture taken along to a result activity
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    }

//if you want to save image

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        //Get Photo
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap  photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);



    }
}
```

Comment: Also when the image dissappears..this appears in the log for the app : 32351-32351/com.andyexample.myapplication E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Comment: You do realise that when you rotate an Android device from landscape to portrait (or vice versa), the `Activity` is destroyed and recreated completely??? In other words, the bitmap retrieved from the camera will be lost and the `ImageView` is simply recreated but it'll be blank until you take another picture.

Answer (score 0):

As @Squonk described, the bitmap is lost when you rotate the device, as the Activity is destroyed and recreated (so that it can create it's layout in the new orientation).

So, you need to save the bitmap as the Activity is destroyed, and read it back when the Activity is recreated.

You can do this as follows:

```
  // save the Activity's instance state as it gets destroyed
  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("bitmap", bitmap);
  }

 // restore any saved instance state
 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
       bitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bitmap");
    }

    if(bitmap != null) {
      imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
 }
```

Note that you will have to make 'bitmap' an instance member of the Activity, instead of a local variable.

Comment: Thanks guys, I get that now but I have to add that even if I hold my phone in a portrait position the screen still comes up landscape then rotates to match the phone then the picture goes? Is that something I done wrong too?

Comment: Also I put in that code you gave me, thank by the way, and it gives me errors for bitmap and photo saying cannot resolve symbol?

Comment: I'll throw up a screenshot now, how do I make bitmap an instance of the activity? Sorry, I know its probably simple but still learning. Its for college an due tomorrow, no fun at all haha!

Comment: Ok I cant post an image yet apparently so all I can say is in the code..Bitmap and photo come up in red. Then where there's (Bitmap bitmap) the second bitmap is red too. The error for each of them says, cannot resolve symbol "Bitmap". Says the same for "photo"

Comment: As I said in my answer, "you will have to make 'bitmap' an instance member of the Activity, instead of a local variable." Sounds like you need to do the same for "photo".

Comment: I seen that but I don't actually know how to do that, I am learning this as I go. Could you tell me how to do it please? Googled it and can't find a real answer

Comment: In your sample code, you have 'imageView' declared at the top of the class (not in a method)..do the same thing for 'bitmap' and 'photo'

Comment: Thanks sorted the Bitmap error but photo still comes up in red and says the following: "set.image.bitmap: (android.graphics.bitmap) in imageview cannot be applied to (android.media.Image)

Answer (score 0):

I found your issue. I got also this issue. but this is solved by save that uri and saveInstance and Restore that savedInstance.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        //Get Photo
        Uri mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageUri(mImageCaptureUri);



    }
}



@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
            outState.putString("cameraImageUri", mImageCaptureUri.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("cameraImageUri")) {
            mImageCaptureUri = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("cameraImageUri"));
        }
    }
```